# Unable to use StructField with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running the PySpark shell and unable to create a dataframe. I've done

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
```

all without any errors returned.

Then I tried running these commands:

```
schemaString = "name age"
fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in schemaString.split()]
```

And keep getting the error: ` name 'StructField' is not defined

Basically, I'm following the Spark documentation here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html

Weird, if I remove the `for` loop and do this, it works:

```
fields = [StructField('field1', StringType(), True)]
```

Comment: I'd double check that you've actually `import`ed `StructField` correctly.

Comment: Ah yeah, looks like I have to do `from pyspark.sql.types import *` instead of `from pyspark.sql import *`

Answer (score 6):

It works for following code. Document for [StructField](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=pyspark.sql.types#pyspark.sql.types.StructField) and [StringType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=pyspark.sql.types#pyspark.sql.types.StringType). While 1.3 is pretty old.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schemaString = "name age"

fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) 
    for field_name in schemaString.split()]
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should import packages like the following:

```
    from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from pyspark.sql import Row
    from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
    from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
    from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
```